# Real analysis uniform convergence interval [-a,a]

Tags: real-analysis

We are given the following series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}*x^{2*n} \;\;\;\;\;\;\; \; x\in \mathbb{R} 
$$

and let $0\leq a<1$

Show the series converges uniformly  in the interval [-a,a]

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n}$$

$$f(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{4}}{4}+\frac{x^{6}}{6}+\frac{x^{8}}{8} +....$$

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{(x^{2})}{1}+\frac{(x^{2})^{2}}{2}+\frac{(x^{2})^{3}}{3}+\frac{(x^{2})^{4}}{4} +....]$$

$$ln(1-x)=-[x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+......]$$

$$f(x)=\frac{-1}{2}ln(1-x^{2})$$

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}ln(1-x^{2})$$

My problem is that I got this help from a person from Chegg and I don't understand if it's correct or not. And why it will make sense .

I would solve it by making a ratio test and find out it will give me  $|x^{2}|$ and if $|x^{2}|<1$ then $-1<x<1$

Later in this question I am asked:

b) show the series sum function  f:(-a,a)$\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and it applies

$$f'(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^{2}} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;x\in(-a,a) $$

$$(f(x))'=(\frac{1}{2}*ln(1-x^{2}))'$$

the constante
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}^{2x}$$

I substitute   $u=1-x^2$ and $f = ln(u)$. 
$$\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{u}(-2x)$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^{2}}$$

c) Determine the sumfunctionen f, and use this to show

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}*n} =log(2)$$

I use at fraction rule to re-write 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}*n} $$
til 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2}^{n}}{n}$$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}^{1}}{1}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}^{2}}{2}+....$$

$$ln(1-x)=-[\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+....]$$

$$ -ln(1-\frac{1}{2})$$
$$-ln(\frac{1}{2})=$$
$$=ln(2)$$

Comment: I suspect the intent is to show uniform convergence of the series on any interval $[-a,a]$ where $0 \leqslant a < 1$ without needing to know what the sum equals.  Try comparing the tail,  $\sum_{n\geqslant N} x^{2n}/(2n) $  with the tail of the convergent sum $\sum_{n  \geqslant N } a^{2n}/(2n) $.  You are trying to illustrate a couple of theorems are (i) every power series converges uniformly on a closed sub-interval inside its radius of convergence and (ii) convergent power series may be differentiated and integrated term by term.